# How to resolve EMR Spark Out Of Memory Error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, out-of-memory, amazon-emr

I have a Spark job which I am trying to execute on EMR. It is giving me the below error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 22611"...
```

I have tried it with even 10 core instances of type m5.12xlarge but still the same issue. My code is working fine as I have tested it via AWS Glue and that has succeeded with G1.X and 20 DPUs (takes around 3 hours to complete the job). Any recommendation regarding how I choose the EMR instance type?

Answer (score 0):

So changing the instance types only won't always help, we need to play with spark configurations as well. I followed something like mentioned [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/) and the job is successful on EMR.